# Pivot datetime index to a start and end column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm having a problem with switching this data:

```
datetime               transmission #
2019-07-12 00:03:06    124
2019-07-12 00:04:56    124
2019-07-12 00:20:10    125
2019-07-12 00:21:33    125
```

to a format like this using the python module pandas:

```
transmission #   start                  end
124              2019-07-12 00:03:06    2019-07-12 00:04:56
125              2019-07-12 00:20:10    2019-07-12 00:21:33
```

At first, I thought I could do this with a pivot where the index was transmission # and the values were `datetime` but I can't seem to make it work.

```
print(df.pivot(index = 'ConnectDisconnect', columns=['start', 'end'], values='data_point_time'))
```

ConnectDisconnect is the `transmission#`. I thought this would work but it just outputs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data.py", line 28, in <module>
    print(df.pivot(index = 'ConnectDisconnect', columns=['start', 'end'], values='data_point_time'))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5067, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'pivot'
```

if anyone could help me out with this, it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=r'\s{2,}', engine='python')
n = len(df.index)//2
x = df['datetime']
# drop the column of 'datetime'
df = df.drop('datetime', axis=1)
# Remove the duplicated row
df = df.drop_duplicates()
df.index=range(n) 
start = x[0::2]
start.index=range(n)
end = x[1::2]
end.index = range(n)
df['start'] =start 
df['end']=end 
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Output is

```
transmission #                start                  end
           124  2019-07-12 00:03:06  2019-07-12 00:04:56
           125  2019-07-12 00:20:10  2019-07-12 00:21:33
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. If you have your datetime as your index column you need to use df.reset_index() to reference the column like df['datetime'].